# Axios 404 (bad request) CreateError

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using the yelp api using react and axios. I believe I have set everything up correctly and when it runs it hits my catch.

I added the cors-anywhere piece after running into some cors issues. Not using a backend, just a front end.

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const App = () => {
      const [bus, setBus] = useState([])

      useEffect (() => {
          axios.get(`${'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'}https://api.yelp.com/v3.businesses/search`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
            },
            params: {
              term: 'food',
            }
          })
            .then( res => {setBus(res.data)
              console.log(bus)
              debugger
            })
            .catch( err => {console.log(err)
              debugger
            })
      })

      return(
        <div>
          {bus ? <h2>Data</h2> : <h2>No Data</h2>}
        </div>
      )

    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: What is `debugger` doing inside your `then` and `catch`?

Comment: I added them just to see which part of the call was being hit, and what data was being passed through.

Comment: Try taking out the $ and brackets from the cors-header part of the URL. Try this: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3.businesses/search`

Comment: You also have a typo in your query. It should be a `/` after `v3` not a period. The root endpoint from the docs is : https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search  and the docs also say you need to pass it a term or id.